# Create index on longtext column with length for MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have created an EFCore migration file in C# for a MySQL database. I am trying to create an index on a longtext column, and I am aware of the fact that you need to specify a length for longtext columns within an index.

Is there any way to do this in code? I have this composite index, with Column2 being longtext:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex("idx_temp", "Table1", new[] { "Column1", "Column2" }, null, false, null);
```

This is failing when pushing the migration file to the database because of the lack of specifying a length for Column2. I can't find any overloads on the CreateIndex method that allows you to specify this.

Where do you specify the length in this context?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `new[] { "Column1(100)", "Column2(100)" }`, where 100 - needed indexed prefix length. PS. Does the index by LONGTEXT makes sense really? maybe index by the column's value hash is enough?

Comment: Thanks Akina! That seems like it could work. I'll give it a spin and let you know if it worked. I see MySQL makes a string field in C# a longtext by default, not sure if that can be changed. Thanks!

Comment: If you cannot implement precise structure from C# code then use raw SQL, not framework, and create the structure which you need in precisely. But firstly investigate the documentation - maybe you simply have not found yet the construction which allows to create the structure you need in...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a UNIQUE index on a text/longtext/blob column in MySQL.

If you are wanting an index on a TEXT or a BLOB field, you must specify a fixed length in order to achieve that.

From MYSQL:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

> BLOB and TEXT columns also can be indexed, but a prefix length must be
> given.

Basic Example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON misc_info (key(10));
```

Though It does seem like something might be wrong with your table design. You might want to post that. Normally you should have something like this:

```
public class MyText
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //leaving this blank it will give you nvarchar(MAX) or longtext basically
    public string Txt { get; set; }
}
```

Though use this sparingly. Leaving strings to be max can be risky in DBs,

Comment: ?? Where you have found that OP needs in UNIQUE index?